# Bayesian simple linear regression Gibbs Sampling with gamma prior

Tags: r

Please help me out.

I am doing Metopolis_hasting within Gibbs to generate a Markov Chian with stationary distribution equal to the joint conditional distribution of (beta,phi) given observed y. Where the model for y is simple linear regression and phi is 1/sigma^2. The full conditional distribution for phi is gamma(shape=shape_0+n/2,rate=rate_0 + 0.5*sum((y$y-b[1]-b[1]*y$x)^2)) where shape_0 and rate_0 are prior distribution of phi (which follows a gamma)

Here is my code:

```
y <- read.table("...",header = T)
n <- 50
shape_0 <- 10
rate_0 <- 25


  shape <- shape_0+n/2

   mcmc <- function (n = 10){
       X <- matrix(0,n,3)
       b <- c(5,2)
       phi <- 0.2 
       X[1,] <- c(b,phi)
       count1 <- 0
       count2 <- 0
      for (i in 2:n){

      phi_new <- rnorm(1,phi,1) #generate new phi candidate 
      rate <- rate_0 + 0.5*sum((y$y-b[1]-b[1]*y$x)^2)

      prob1 <- min(dgamma(phi_new,shape = shape, 
       rate =   rate)/dgamma(phi,shape = shape, rate = rate),1)
      ##here is where I run into trouble, dgamma(phi_new,shape = shape, 
       ##rate =   rate) 
       ##and dgamma(phi,shape = shape, rate = rate) both gives 0

     u <- runif(1)
      if (prob1>u)
      {X[i,3] <- phi_new; count1=count1+1}
        else  {X[i,3] <-phi}

       phi <- X[i,3]

 ....}
```

I know I should use log transformation on the precision parameter, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. log(dgamma(phi_new,shape = shape, rate = rate)) would return -inf.

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: All distribution related functions in `R` has a `log` (or `log.p`) argument that returns the logarithm of the desired quantity and can handle a much bigger range of values. This is just a comment on the last lines; I didn't go over the code. I guess your problem belongs to stats and not programming.